# How to replace derivation sign(example: u^(1,2,0)) with it's some permutation?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I am having problem while replacing derivation sign with it's some permutation.

```
u^(1,0,0)./{?} = u^(0,1,0).
```

But I just know, that 1st->2nd, 2nd -> 1st, 3rd -> 3rd of (1,0,0).

Is there any way to write such replacing with pattern matching or etc. ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) operates on the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression

```
expr = Derivative[1, 0, 0][u]
```

[image]

```
expr /. Derivative[f_, s_, t_][u] :> Derivative[s, f, t][u]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I second Bob Hanlon's suggestion of `ReplaceAll`, but ou can also express the permutation you've described simply in terms of [`Cycles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cycles.html) as

```
permutation = Cycles[{{1,2,3}}];
```

Then you can apply that permutation directly to derivative (so its indices will be permuted):

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u] /. d_Derivative[u] :> Permute[d, permutation][u]
(* Derivative[0, 1, 0][u] *)
```

Comment: Note that `Permute` operates on any expression, not just lists: `Derivative[1, 0, 0][u] /. d : Derivative[__] :> Permute[d, permutation]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 good point; updated.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
expr = Derivative[a, b, c][u]

#[[0, {2, 1, 3}]] @@ # & @expr
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
MapAt[Permute[#, {2, 1, 3}] &, expr, {0}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nice +1. i think the indices should be {2,1,3} in `MapAt`?

Answer (score 3):

```
expr /. {(p : Derivative[PatternSequence[1, 0, 0]])[u] :> 
Operate[RotateRight, p[u]], (q : Derivative[PatternSequence[0, 1, 0]])[u] :> 
Operate[RotateLeft, q[u]]}
```

Comment: Like `Permute`, `RotateRight` etc. operate on any expression: `Derivative[1, 0, 0][u] /. d : Derivative[__] :> RotateRight[d]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for letting me know. i changed the answer. thought that `Operate` can work well in such cases

Comment: Yes, `Operate` is a nice variation.

Comment: (+1)  why not just `Operate[RotateRight, expr]` or `Operate[Permute[#, {2, 1, 3}] &, expr]`?

Comment: @kglr it works beautifully in your case but don't you reckon that i need to specify which way to Rotate i.e. right or left ? I may be incorrect

Comment: @Ali, `RotateRight/Left` work for the specific example in the question. In general, we need  to permute the arguments. Also, perhaps  `Operate[#[[{2, 1, 3}]] &, expr]`  is cleaner than `Operate[Permute[#, {2, 1, 3}] &, expr]`.

Comment: @kglr thanks. i see what you mean.